# Unable to install DotNetNuke on Windows 10 with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis, installation, dotnetnuke

Having Windows 10 with IIS 10.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2, I am unable to carry on through the DNN installation wizard (Noting that I am trying to install the version 9.1.1 which seems to be the latest version for now).

The error snapshot is shown over this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PRJh.png)

I already tested IIS and it is working, tested SQL Server, tested authentication via both Windows integrated authentication and SQL Server authentication.

I created a database named nukeDB on my localhost with a dedicated username and password and logged in through SQL Server Management Studio without any problem.

However, on the first step of the installation wizard, I got the following error:

> ERROR: DotNetNuke requires SQL Server 2008 (express or full product) to work

It seems for me that this is an incompatibility issue! Am I true?

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/476976/scope/posts/error-dotnetnuke-requires-sql-2008-express-or-full-product-to-work

Comment: thank you dear@dfundako. I already read that several times. It is almost null. Just saying to have a fresh install of DNN. Moreover the provided link is no more valid.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the SQL connection screen (in the DNN setup) that you are selecting the options for. I haven't tried 9.1.1 fresh install on 2008, but I do have some sites running 9.1.1 running on 2008 that upgraded from earlier versions of DNN

Comment: Try some of the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci

Comment: @ChrisHammond. The snapshot is shown here  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PRJh.png

Comment: Thank you @VDWWD. It is really helpful link.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008 R2 why do you have .\SqlExpress as the name of the server?

Comment: Seems that the problem is here. I had an old SQLExpress 2005 which is used by default. Then, after updating 2005 to 2008, I did not install a new node for 2008. Thank you @ChrisHammond

Comment: Anyway, SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported on Windows 10 or Windows Server 2016. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2681562/using-sql-server-in-windows-8-and-later-versions-of-windows-operating